# Is there PvP in Diablo 3? How does it work?

Tags: diablo-iii

From my very limited experience during the open beta weekend I couldn't figure out a way to attack other players during the beta campaign. Is this possible in the release or will multiplayer only reflect on trading and co-operative games?

Comment: There is no need to litter your questions with tags. The diablo-series tag is for questions that transcend a single game. Most of the time, just tagging with the name of the game is enough.

Comment: Is this such a controversial question that it was closed, reopened, and has 3 upvotes and 2 downvotes all in 20 minutes?

Comment: There was a discussion about this question in chat. Originally it was worded like future speculation which is off topic, but after some discussion it was decided that minor edits would make it a valid question, and so we enacted those changes to save the question. All downvotes have since been rescinded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pvp was added in [patch 1.0.7](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/game/patch-notes/1-0-7). It is called [Brawling](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/game/guide/gameplay/pvp). For details click the link [Brawling](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/game/guide/gameplay/pvp).

> You can brawl with other players in your party, either one on one or
>   in a group free-for-all, to prove your dominance. There are no rules,
>   scores, or limits.
>
> When you want to start something, talk to Nek the Brawler. You'll find
>   him in each act’s town area, near the waypoint.
>
> Nek will transport you to the ideal environment for a fight – The
>   Scorched Chapel, a flat land that includes flowing waters, a brick
>   church, and a graveyard with room for new arrivals. Any members of
>   your party can join you there by speaking to Nek. Brawling is opt-in –
>   you won’t get attacked by anyone who isn’t in a group with you and
>   currently present in the Scorched Chapel.
>
> When you die in the Chapel, you’ll reappear there (even if you’re a
>   hardcore character, your death isn’t permanent). You won’t lose any
>   equipment durability for participating (or perishing) in a brawl.

Comment: I'm not sure why you had a downvote, but I've gone ahead and voted it up.  I'm gonna guess the original downvote was because pre-edit you only had links.

Comment: Yeah, i think it was because of just links. However, i just copy and pasted what the link says. lol

Comment: I mean, that's all that's needed.  Just gotta be careful of link-rot, should the page be removed or the URL changed, which would have made the original almost worthless.

Comment: Agreed. I assumed that was the reason. Why i fixed it. =)

Answer (score 10):

PvP will not be available immediately; Blizzard has said this will be coming in a later patch so they can get the game out to us hungry people sooner.

http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/4574895

> #### Diablo III PvP Update
>
> As we're counting down the days until we're ready to announce a release date for Diablo III, we've come to realize that the PvP game and systems aren't yet living up to our standards. Today, we wanted to let you know that we've made the difficult decision to hold back the PvP Arena system and release it in a patch following the game's launch.

As for how it will look when done:

> When the PvP patch is ultimately ready, it will add multiple Arena maps with themed locations and layouts, PvP-centric achievements, and a matchmaking system that will help you and your team get into fairly matched games quickly and easily.

Comment: Will the PvP maps be procedurally generated like the dungeons I wonder?

Comment: @Muhd - What they have shown in the past is an Arena type game, where 8 players are able to simply attack one another, in an Arena style map.